# 2011 Ford Escape has an oil leak

Tags: ford, oil-leak, escape

A 2011 Ford Escape with about 150K miles on it is leaking about one quart of oil every other  week. The owner of the car plans to replace it next year. However, with the oil leak she has concerns that the car will be hard to sell. There is also the concern the oil leak might get significantly worse.

There are fluids that can be purchased that claim to eliminate (or at least reduce this) oil leak. Do you think it would be a good thing to try? Are they safe?

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It has been my experience these types of products don't work very well and just end up costing you money without any real return on investment. The way that most of them work is by causing rubber to plump up, which can stem the flow of oil if the leak is occurring somewhere there's rubber. They may do other things too, but realistically they aren't worth the money.

Are they safe? It depends on what you mean by safe, but for the most part I don't think they'll cause you, the person who owns the car, or the car itself any issues. Now, I wouldn't recommend drinking it.

A better solution might be to figure out where the oil is leaking from and ascertain if you or someone with some mad mechanic's skills to can fix them on the cheap. It might be an easy to replace valve cover gasket. Might be something worse. That said, if you can cut the oil use in 1/2, you'd be doing something which would be helping. This is just a thought, though.